# Problem with strong type-checking in lint (warning 632)

Tags: c, lint, strong-typing

I'm working to polish some existing C code in order to port it to a new compiler (embedded software, we're switching hardware). So I'm trying to scrub the current code with lint, and I'm stumped by an assignment that lint has decided is a strong-typing violation.

The error I'm getting:

```
--- Module:   GenericFileName.c 
GenericFileName.c  ...  Warning 632: Assignment to strong type
(SubStructureType_T) in context: assignment
```

The lines of code to which it refers (names changed for readability):

```
void foo(void)
{
    extern const StructureType_T parent;    
    const SubStructureType_T *localChild;

    localChild = parent.child;   //<-- lint complains about this assignment
    ...
}
```

The relevant parts of StructureType_T:

```
typedef struct
{   
    const struct SubStructureType_T *child;
    ...
}StructureType_T;
```

And finally, the lint option to enable strong-type checking:

```
-strong(AcXJcb)
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I've searched around for help on this but haven't found much. I guess lint is a pretty old tool. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Where and how is `parent` actually (globally)defined which you have asked external linkage for ?

Comment: Oops, very good question. I should have included that. It looks like this: 'const StructureType_T parent = { 0,0,0,...,0}'. It lives in another module.

Comment: `const StructureType_T parent = { 0,0,0,...,0};`

Comment: This is not really helpful. Since you said it is a old tool, try setting to **NULL** instead of **0** in the initializer list for the pointer.

Comment: Is this relevant? I've got the definition after a `#pragma tsection .parent` statement. Due to the vital nature of the application, we use this type of thing to be very deliberate about where some addresses are stored.

Comment: Tried setting it to **NULL** in the instantiation, unfortunately I am still getting the warning from lint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it `const SubStructureType_T`, as in `foo`, or `const struct SubStructureType_T` as in the `typedef`? Note that the keyword "struct" only appears in the 2nd definition.

Are they the same?

Comment: Oh, of course. I need to have `struct` in the declaration for `*localChild`. I feel silly now. Thanks!

Comment: +1, I bet that's it.  See the question [Difference between `struct` and `typedef struct`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c) for details.

Comment: @Adam @pmg Absolutely. Because I need to use forward declaration, the SubStructureType_T is defined like so: `typedef struct SubStructure_T{ ... } SubStructure_T;`. I'm not sure any compiler would have mistakenly tried to make `localChild` something strange without the `struct`, but this fix makes lint happy. Thanks again.

Comment: What's the harm of keeping `typedef` away from the code and type an extra `struct` everytime it's needed? Don't answer: rhetoric question :)